# SQLite - RecyclerView - many tables do not work

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a problem with creating two tables in sqlite and display them in RecyclerView and more specifically with one table. I add to the question a screenshot of the application so that you can understand what the problem is.

I have 3 activities: FirstActivity, in which there are two buttons (Monday and Tuesday) -> from this activity we go to MainActivity, on the button selection (Monday) -> save data in table_MON and after selection button (Tuesday) in the table_Tue. The problem is that everything works correctly, when we press the button (Monday) we can save the training, edit and delete it. However, when we go to the button (Tuesday) we can only add training, but we can't edit or delete them. However, I have no idea why? I am already looking at this problem for a week and I have no idea what is going on, maybe a fresh look will help solve the problem.
My database consists of two tables: tableMon and tableTue, but I use the same columns in it (exercises, weight etc ..), and separate _id, and I do not know if this can be a problem. Perhaps the problem is that I use MainActivity in both cases?

**Screenshot App:**

***FirstActivity***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWjAb.png)

***Click button Monday --> MainActivity.class***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBRFV.png)

***Click button Tuesday --> MainActivity.class***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIhRU.png)

***Button Tuesday --> DetailActivity and her is the problem I can't update and delete training.***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5b8g.png)

**FirstActivity.class**

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button buttonMon, buttonTue;

    public static final String BUTTON_KEY1 = "BUTTON_KEY";
    public static final String BUTTON_KEY2 = "BUTTON_KEY2";
    public static final String BUTTON_VALUE = "1";
    public static final String BUTTON_VALUE2 = "2";

    public static  boolean WAS_RUNNING;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        buttonMon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMonday);
        buttonTue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTuesday);

        WAS_RUNNING = false;

        //OPEN THE SAME MAINACTIVITY
        buttonMon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WAS_RUNNING = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(BUTTON_KEY1, BUTTON_VALUE);

                startActivity(intent);
            }    });
        //OPEN THE SAME MAINACTIVITY
        buttonTue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WAS_RUNNING = true;
                Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(BUTTON_KEY2, BUTTON_VALUE2);
                startActivity(i);
            }    });}}
```

***MainActivity.class***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    private ArrayList<Training> trainingArrayList = new ArrayList<Training>();

    private EditText editTextExercise, editTextWeight, editTextRepeat, editTextSeries;
    private Button buttonSave, buttonBack;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private String value;
    private String value2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();}});

        if(bundle == null)
        {return;}

        value = bundle.getString(FirstActivity.BUTTON_KEY1);

        value2 = bundle.getString(FirstActivity.BUTTON_KEY2);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        if(value != null) {

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, trainingArrayList);

            //Refresh MON TABLE
            refreshMonTable();

        }else if(value2 != null) {

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, trainingArrayList);

            //Refresh TUE TABLE
            refreshTueTable(); }}

    public void showDialog()
    {
         dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

        editTextExercise = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(editTextExerciseDialog);
        editTextWeight = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(editTextWeightDialog);
        editTextRepeat = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(editTextRepeatDialog);
        editTextSeries = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(editTextSeriesDialog);

        buttonSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(buttonSaveDialog);
        buttonBack = (Button) dialog.findViewById(buttonBackDialog);

        buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();}});

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(value != null) {
                    saveDataMon(editTextExercise.getText().toString(),
                            String.valueOf(editTextWeight.getText().toString()),
                            String.valueOf(editTextRepeat.getText().toString()),
                            String.valueOf(editTextSeries.getText().toString()));
                } else if(value2 != null) {
                    saveDataTue(editTextExercise.getText().toString(),
                            String.valueOf(editTextWeight.getText().toString()),
                            String.valueOf(editTextRepeat.getText().toString()),
                            String.valueOf(editTextSeries.getText().toString()));
                }}});

        dialog.show();}

    private void saveDataMon(String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series)
    {
            DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(this);

            adapter.openDatabase();

            long result = adapter.addMon(exercise, weight, repeat, series);

            if (result > 0) {
                editTextExercise.setText("");
                editTextWeight.setText("");
                editTextRepeat.setText("");
                editTextSeries.setText("");

                dialog.dismiss();

            } else {
                Snackbar.make(editTextExercise, "Unable to save!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            adapter.closeDB();

            refreshMonTable();}

    private void saveDataTue(String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series)
    {
        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(this);

            adapter.openDatabase();

            long result = adapter.addTue(exercise, weight, repeat, series);

            if (result > 0) {
                editTextExercise.setText("");
                editTextWeight.setText("");
                editTextRepeat.setText("");
                editTextSeries.setText("");

                dialog.dismiss();

            } else {
                Snackbar.make(editTextExercise, "Unable to save!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            adapter.closeDB();

            refreshTueTable();}

    private void refreshMonTable()
    {
        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(this);

        adapter.openDatabase();

        trainingArrayList.clear();

        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllTreningMon();

        if(cursor != null)
        { if(cursor.moveToFirst())
         {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String cwiczenie = cursor.getString(1);
                String ciezar = cursor.getString(2);
                String powtorzenia = cursor.getString(3);
                String serie = cursor.getString(4);

                Training training = new Training(id, cwiczenie, ciezar, powtorzenia, serie);
                trainingArrayList.add(training);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());}}

        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        adapter.closeDB(); }

   private void refreshTueTable()
    {
        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(this);

        adapter.openDatabase();

        trainingArrayList.clear();

        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllTreningTue();

        if(cursor != null)
        { if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String exercise = cursor.getString(1);
                String weight = cursor.getString(2);
                String repeat = cursor.getString(3);
                String series = cursor.getString(4);

                Training training = new Training(id, exercise, weight, repeat, series);
                trainingArrayList.add(training);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());}}

        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        adapter.closeDB();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

       if(value != null) {
            //REFRESH
           refreshMonTable();
        } else if(value2 != null) {
           refreshTueTable();}}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Exit?")
                .setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();}}
```

***DetailActivity.class***

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextExerciseDetail, editTextWeightDetail, editTextRepeatDetail, editTextSeriesDetail;

    private Button buttonUpdate;
    private Button buttonDelete;

    String mon;
    String tue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(intent == null)
        {return;}

                mon = intent.getString(MyAdapter.KEY_MON);
                tue = intent.getString(MyAdapter.KEY_TUE);

            final int idT = intent.getInt("id");
            String cwiczenie = intent.getString("exercise");
            String ciezar = intent.getString("weight");
            String powtorzenia = intent.getString("repeat");
            String serie = intent.getString("series");

        editTextExerciseDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.exerciseEditTxtDetail);
        editTextWeightDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightEditTextDetail);
        editTextRepeatDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repeatEditTextDetail);
        editTextSeriesDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seriesEditTextDetail);

        buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);
        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

        editTextExerciseDetail.setText(cwiczenie);
        editTextWeightDetail.setText(ciezar);
        editTextRepeatDetail.setText(powtorzenia);
        editTextSeriesDetail.setText(serie);

        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mon != null) {
                    updateMon(idT, editTextExerciseDetail.getText().toString(),
                            editTextWeightDetail.getText().toString(),
                            editTextRepeatDetail.getText().toString(),
                            editTextSeriesDetail.getText().toString());
                } else if(tue != null) {
                    updateTue(idT, editTextExerciseDetail.getText().toString(),
                            editTextWeightDetail.getText().toString(),
                            editTextRepeatDetail.getText().toString(),
                            editTextSeriesDetail.getText().toString());}}
        });

        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailActivity.this);

                builder.setMessage("Do you want delete this training?")
                        .setTitle("Delete")
                        .create();

               builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       if(mon != null) {
                           deleteMon(idT);
                       }else if(tue != null){
                           deleteTue(idT);}}});

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }});
                builder.show();}});}

    //Update MON TABLE
    private void updateMon(int id, String newExercise, String newWeight, String newRepeat, String newSeries)
    {
        DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.openDatabase();

        long result = dbAdapter.updateMon(id, newExercise, newWeight, newRepeat, newSeries);

        if(result > 0)
        {
            editTextExerciseDetail.setText(newExercise);
            editTextWeightDetail.setText(newWeight);
            editTextRepeatDetail.setText(newRepeat);
            editTextSeriesDetail.setText(newSeries);

            this.finish();

            Snackbar.make(editTextExerciseDetail, "Updated Succesfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else
        {
            Snackbar.make(editTextExerciseDetail, "Unable to updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        dbAdapter.closeDB();
    }

    //Update TUE TABLE
    private void updateTue(int id, String newExercise, String newWeight, String newRepeat, String newSeries)
    {
        DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.openDatabase();

        long result = dbAdapter.updateTue(id, newExercise, newWeight, newRepeat, newSeries);

        if(result > 0)
        {
            editTextExerciseDetail.setText(newExercise);
            editTextWeightDetail.setText(newWeight);
            editTextRepeatDetail.setText(newRepeat);
            editTextSeriesDetail.setText(newSeries);

            this.finish();

            Snackbar.make(editTextExerciseDetail, "Updated Succesfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else
        {
            Snackbar.make(editTextExerciseDetail, "Unable to updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        dbAdapter.closeDB();}

    //DELETE MON TABLE
   private void deleteMon(int id)
   {
       DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
       dbAdapter.openDatabase();

       long result = dbAdapter.deleteMon(id);

       if(result>0)
       {
           this.finish();

       }else
       {
           Snackbar.make(editTextExerciseDetail, "Unable to deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       dbAdapter.closeDB();
   }

    //DELETE TUE TABLE
    private void deleteTue(int id)
    {
        DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.openDatabase();

        long result = dbAdapter.deleteTue(id);

        if(result>0)
        {
            this.finish();

        }else
        {
            Snackbar.make(editTextExerciseDetail, "Unable to deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dbAdapter.closeDB();}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();}
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();}}
```

***DBHelper.class***

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //DB
    static final String DB_NAME = "training_db";

    static final int DB_VERSION = '1';

    //TABLES
    static final String TB_NAME_MON = "training_tb_mon";
    static final String TB_NAME_TUE = "training_tb_tue";

    //COLUMNS
    static final String ROW_ID_MON = "id_Mon";
    static final String ROW_ID_TUE = "id_Tue";

    //ROW
    static final String EXERCISE = "exercise";
    static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
    static final String REPEAT = "repeat";
    static final String SERIES = "series";

    static final String CREATE_TB_MON = "CREATE TABLE training_tb_mon (id_Mon INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "exercise TEXT NOT NULL, weight TEXT NOT NULL, repeat TEXT NOT NULL, series TEXT NOT NULL);";

    static final String CREATE_TB_TUE = "CREATE TABLE training_tb_tue (id_Tue INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
           + "exercise TEXT NOT NULL, weight TEXT NOT NULL, repeat TEXT NOT NULL, series TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TB_MON);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TB_TUE);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_NAME_MON);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_NAME_TUE);

        onCreate(db);
    }}
```

***DBAdapter.class***

```
public class DBAdapter {

    Context c;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(c);
    }

    //OPEN DATABASE
    public DBAdapter openDatabase() {

        try {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return this;
    }
    //CLOSE DATABASE
    public void closeDB()
    {
        try{
            dbHelper.close();
        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

    //Add training Mon
    public long addMon(String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series)
    {
        try{
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.EXERCISE, exercise);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.WEIGHT, weight);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.REPEAT, repeat);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.SERIES, series);
            return db.insert(DBHelper.TB_NAME_MON, DBHelper.ROW_ID_MON, contentValues);

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();   }
        return 0;}
    //Add training Tue
    public long addTue(String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series)
    {
        try{
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.EXERCISE, exercise);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.WEIGHT, weight);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.REPEAT, repeat);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.SERIES, series);
            return db.insert(DBHelper.TB_NAME_TUE, DBHelper.ROW_ID_TUE, contentValues);

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    //REFRESH TABLE MON

    public long updateMon(int id, String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series)
    {
       try{
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.EXERCISE, exercise);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.WEIGHT, weight);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.REPEAT, repeat);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.SERIES, series);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.ROW_ID_MON, id);

            return db.update(DBHelper.TB_NAME_MON, contentValues, DBHelper.ROW_ID_MON + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   }
       return 0;
    }

    //REFRESH TABLE TUE
    public long updateTue(int id, String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series)
    {
        try{
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.EXERCISE, exercise);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.WEIGHT, weight);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.REPEAT, repeat);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.SERIES, series);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.ROW_ID_TUE, id);

            return db.update(DBHelper.TB_NAME_TUE, contentValues, DBHelper.ROW_ID_TUE + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    //DELETE ROW TABLE MON
    public long deleteMon(int id)
    {
        try{
            return db.delete(DBHelper.TB_NAME_MON, DBHelper.ROW_ID_MON + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
       }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;    }

    //DELETE ROW TABLE TUE
    public long deleteTue(int id)
    {
        try{
            return db.delete(DBHelper.TB_NAME_TUE, DBHelper.ROW_ID_TUE + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();}

        return 0;}

    //ALL TRAINING TABLE MON

    public Cursor getAllTreningMon() {

        try{
            String[] columns = {DBHelper.ROW_ID_MON, DBHelper.EXERCISE, DBHelper.WEIGHT, DBHelper.REPEAT, DBHelper.SERIES};

            return db.query(DBHelper.TB_NAME_MON, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        }catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    //ALL TRAINING TABLE TUE
   public Cursor getAllTreningTue() {

        try{
            String[] columns = {DBHelper.ROW_ID_TUE, DBHelper.EXERCISE, DBHelper.WEIGHT, DBHelper.REPEAT, DBHelper.SERIES};

            return db.query(DBHelper.TB_NAME_TUE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        }catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;}}
```

***MyAdapter.class***

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<Training> training;

    public static String KEY_MON = "KEY_MON";
    public static String KEY_TUE = "KEY_TUE";
    public static String VALUE_MON = "10";
    public static String VALUE_TUE = "20";

    public <T extends Training> MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Training> training) {
        this.c = c;
        this.training = training;
    }
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.card_view_model, parent, false);

        return new MyHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.textViewModel.setText(training.get(position).getExercise());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v) {
                if (FirstActivity.WAS_RUNNING)

                {Intent intent = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(KEY_MON, VALUE_MON);
                    intent.putExtra("id", training.get(position).getId());
                    intent.putExtra("exercise", training.get(position).getExercise());
                    intent.putExtra("weight", training.get(position).getWeight());
                    intent.putExtra("repeat", training.get(position).getRepeat());
                    intent.putExtra("series", training.get(position).getSeries());

                    c.startActivity(intent);

                } else if (FirstActivity.WAS_RUNNING)

                {Intent intent2 = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);

                    intent2.putExtra(KEY_TUE, VALUE_TUE);
                    intent2.putExtra("id", training.get(position).getId());
                    intent2.putExtra("exercise", training.get(position).getExercise());
                    intent2.putExtra("weight", training.get(position).getWeight());
                    intent2.putExtra("repeat", training.get(position).getRepeat());
                    intent2.putExtra("series", training.get(position).getSeries());

                    c.startActivity(intent2);
                }}});}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return training.size();}}
```

***Training.class***

```
public class Training {

     int id;
     String exercise;
     String weight;
     String repeat;
     String series;
    public Training(int id, String exercise, String weight, String repeat, String series) {
        this.id = id;
        this.exercise = exercise;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.repeat = repeat;
        this.series = series;
    }
    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id;}
    public String getExercise() {return exercise; }
    public void setExercise(String exercise) {this.exercise = exercise;}
    public String getWeight() {return weight;}
    public void setWeight(String weight) {this.weight = weight; }
    public String getRepeat() {return repeat;}
    public void setRepeat(String repeat) { this.repeat = repeat;}
    public String getSeries() {return series;}
    public void setSeries(String series) {this.series = series;}}
```

Comment: Please don't post the whole project, here. Only the **relevant bits**.

Comment: @Noise Generator Sorry. So, should I edit the question and leave only a piece of code that does not work? Is there somewhere  places where I might the whole project?

Comment: Only the piece you suspect being wrong. No. Not on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MyAdapter class, in the `onItemClick` method, within the `onBindViewHolder` method, the second check,  for **Tue** processing, would never run.

You have :-

```
if (FirstActivity.WAS_RUNNING) {
    .......
} else if (FirstActivity.WAS_RUNNING) {
    .......
}
```

i.e. you are saying if FirstActivity was not running and the FirstActivity was running then do your stuff.
 i.e. the **`else`** will only be entered if FirstActivity were not running, in which case the `if (FirstActivity.WAS_RUNNING)` would never be true.

Perhaps have  2 booleans MONDAY_WAS_RUNNING and TUESDAY_WAS RUNNING (you could use just the existing boolean by setting that to false in the buttonTue listener doing the Tuesday processing in the else (without an if) ).

e.g. :-

#### FirstActivity class :-

```
    public static  boolean MONDAY_WAS_RUNNING;
    public static  boolean TUESDAY_WAS_RUNNING;

    ..........


    buttonMon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MONDAY_WAS_RUNNING = true;
            TUESDAY_WAS_RUNNING = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(BUTTON_KEY1, BUTTON_VALUE);

            startActivity(intent);
        }    });
        buttonTue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TUESDAY_WAS_RUNNING = true;
            MONDAY_WAS_RUNNING = false;
            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(BUTTON_KEY2, BUTTON_VALUE2);
            startActivity(i);
        }    });}}
```

#### MyAdapter :-

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.textViewModel.setText(training.get(position).getExercise());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v) {
                if (FirstActivity.MONDAY_WAS_RUNNING)

                {Intent intent = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(KEY_MON, VALUE_MON);
                    intent.putExtra("id", training.get(position).getId());
                    intent.putExtra("exercise", training.get(position).getExercise());
                    intent.putExtra("weight", training.get(position).getWeight());
                    intent.putExtra("repeat", training.get(position).getRepeat());
                    intent.putExtra("series", training.get(position).getSeries());

                    c.startActivity(intent);

                } else if (FirstActivity.TUESDAY_WAS_RUNNING)

                {Intent intent2 = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);

                    intent2.putExtra(KEY_TUE, VALUE_TUE);
                    intent2.putExtra("id", training.get(position).getId());
                    intent2.putExtra("exercise", training.get(position).getExercise());
                    intent2.putExtra("weight", training.get(position).getWeight());
                    intent2.putExtra("repeat", training.get(position).getRepeat());
                    intent2.putExtra("series", training.get(position).getSeries());

                    c.startActivity(intent2);
                }}});}
```

However I'd probably go for :-

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, final int position) {
           holder.textViewModel.setText(training.get(position).getExercise());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);
                if (FirstActivity.MONDAY_WAS_RUNNING) {
                    intent.putExtra(KEY_MON, VALUE_MON);
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra(KEY_TUE, VALUE_TUE);
                }                       
                intent.putExtra("id", training.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("exercise", training.get(position).getExercise());
                intent.putExtra("weight", training.get(position).getWeight());
                intent.putExtra("repeat", training.get(position).getRepeat());
                intent.putExtra("series", training.get(position).getSeries());
                c.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
```

***Note! the above code has not been checked, rather it is in-principle code***

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much! I spend a few day and nothing.. and now everything works well.

Comment: I have corrected my code exactly this way and everything works, so thank you again for your work.

Comment: @recyclerview np.